# How to contract "good one"?

Tags: apostrophe, contractions

Does anyone here know how to contract "good one"?

I have seen it written as "good'un", but that doesn't make much sense to me; as I understand it, the apostrophe is there in place of an omitted letter (or letters, if they are contiguous), but that isn't the case here. The "o" isn't removed, just changed to a "u" - it's the "e" that's lost. Moreover, it isn't in the dictionary.

The sound we make is close to "goodun", but that would create a new word that isn't in the dictionary either, so that won't do.

The more logical solution would be "good un'", but that just looks ridiculous.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The contraction **'un** (old 'un, good 'un, etc) is common for 'one' in informal speech and writing, especially when dialect speech is being represented. Not all apostrophes stand for missing letters.

Comment: [Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/good-un-bad-un-little-un-etc) has "good 'un" listed (spoken-only), but note _Teachers and careful speakers of English do not use this expression_. See also [*'un*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/un#un__5).

Answer (score 1):

The **sound** /w/ in *one* is lost when you're contracting *one* /wʌn/ to *'un* /ən/. It wasn't written in the spelling in the first place, but nevertheless, that's what the apostrophe stands for. Were you expecting English spelling to make perfect sense?